# Plus and Minus icons on bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between plus and minus icon for bootstrap accordion. On default, plus icon is showing. When accordion collapses, it shows the minus icons and hides the plus icon. I don't know if what I'm saying makes sense but it's really basic for some of you. I'm just a beginner.

I've tried doing it with css with :after and content "+" and content "-" but this is not what I want. I need to use font awesome. I've also tried the js way.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

// Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        });
    });

</script>

<body>
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content container-fluid">
        <legend><?php echo $header_title; ?></legend>
        <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 accordion-container">
                    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                        <div class="card">

                            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                                <h2 class="mb-0" style="margin: 10px !important">
                                    <button id="btnCollapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    Card Info
                                    </button>
                                </h2>
                            </div>

                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

I don't know how to check where I went wrong. All I want is to show the plus and minus icon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alex, your code is working fine. Please check this fiddle.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap][1]
```

Please make sure your js code must be written after the jquery.js and bootstrap.js loaded.

Comment: Hi yes. A rookie mistake, I forgot to put the jquery script.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
  $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
  }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
  });
});

/*$("#btnCollapse").on("click", function() {

  $(".fa-plus").toggleClass("fa-minus");

})
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content container-fluid">
      <legend>
        <?php echo $header_title; ?>
      </legend>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 accordion-container">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="card">

              <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h2 class="mb-0" style="margin: 10px !important">
                  <button id="btnCollapse" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Card Info
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                </h2>
              </div>

              <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate solution as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add minus icon for collapse element which is open by default
    $(".collapse.show").each(function(){
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
    });

    // Toggle plus minus icon on show hide of collapse element
    $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
    }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    });
});
```